# Needing to iterate values in a fixed array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

I need help understanding how to iterate values in a fixed array. I don't know if there is a function in `numpy` that does it for you. To better understand my question, here is an example. I have a fixed array of 10.

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[42, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
.
.
.
[37, 15, 20, 60, 39, 10, 5, 3, 42, 9]
```

Once I hit index `10`, the first value `1` disappears from the array.

Can someone tell me the proper name for this technique and if there is a built-in function?

Comment: How do you insert values into array? Or you just need insert() function that does shift of all values and than inserts a new one ?

Comment: I think if you use the `insert()` function, you are also expanding the shape of the array. If I want my array to be fixed, I don't think it will work, right? I will try it out right now.